# How to get the total value from an ArrayList where one is product and the other one is price?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to get the total value from all the products purchased of the Cart.
This information came from an ArrayList but I am not sure if the code I am doing is correct.

```
​public class Cart {

    // creating a new list every time so need to modify..it will hold the list
    private List<CartLine> cartLineList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     *
     * @return the actual cartline list
     */
    public List<CartLine> getCartLineList() {
            return cartLineList;
    }

    public double getTotalValue(List<CartLine> cartLineList)
    {
         //TODO implement the method
        //return Products*Price
        double results=0;
    //  for(CartLine cartLine: getCartLineList()){
            //results += (cartLine.getQuantity()* cartLine.getProduct().getPrice());
        //}

        return results;

    }


   //more code here...
```

### }

this what CartLine looks like

public class CartLine {

```
private Product product;
private int quantity;

public CartLine(Product product, int quantity) {
    this.product = product;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public double getSubtotal() {
    return quantity * product.getPrice();
}

public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(Product product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

}

Comment: From a quick glance, the code you have commented in the for loop looks correct for the question in your header. (i.e. get total price of items in cart) `results += (cartLine.getQuantity()* cartLine.getProduct().getPrice());` small edit of `cartLine.getProduct().getQuantity()` instead of `cartLine.getQuantity()` My assumption here is that a cartLine has various products on it, that can vary with price

Comment: Can you show us what `CartLine` is?

Comment: Yes sure I can show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getQuantity` does returns the amount purchased, and `.getProduct().getPrice()` returns the price of the item, then the summation code looks fine (only commented out). Here's what it should look like:

```
public double getTotalValue(List<CartLine> cartLineList) {
    double results = 0;
    for(CartLine cartLine: getCartLineList()){
        results += (cartLine.getQuantity() * cartLine.getProduct().getPrice());
    }
    return results;
}
```

It would be helpful if you showed us what `CartLine` is. Could there be different products with different prices in the same `CartLine` instance?

Comment: Hi Malth thanks for answer. I think one product has a fixed price. I modifed my post so you can take a look what CartLine looks like.

Comment: If ‘Product’ had a single price, it looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same answer but using lambdas

```
 Collector<CartLine, double[], double[]> productSumCollector = Collector.of(
        () -> new double[1],
        (result, cartLine) -> result[0] += (cartLine.getQuantity() * cartLine.getProduct().getPrice()),
        (result1, result2) -> {
             result1[0] += result2[0];
             return result1;
        }
    );

return Arrays.stream(cartLines).collect(productSumCollector)[0];
```

For reference see https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-07-java-8-creating-a-custom-collector-for-your-stream/